# Update Array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am coming from Angular 1.x and looking to update an unordered list with React / Redux.

In console.log, I am seeing the array being updated, but it doesn't seem to bind to the DOM. I have the following --

> onKeyPress of an input, I have a function that pushes to messages array.

```
<ul className="list-inline">
  {messages.map(function(message, key){
    return (
      <li key={key} message={message}>{message}</li>
    );
  })}
</ul>
```

**Update**
I have the following (but no luck yet) Some notes. I am using Firebase to listen for events, and add to an array. Wondering if its a bind issue? --

```
class Comments extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {messages: this.props.messages};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const path = '/comments/all';
    // Firebase watches for new comments
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(path)
      .on('child_added', (dataSnapshot) => {
          this.state.messages.push(dataSnapshot.val());
          this.setState({
            messages: this.state.messages
          });
          //console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
      });
  }

  render() {
    const messages = this.state.messages;
    return (
      <ul className="list-inline">
        {messages.map(function(message, key){
          <li key={key}>{message}</li>
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, your [currently-accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39044375/157247) is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need messages to be set in the components `state`.

```
getInitialState() {
  return {
    messages: []
  }
}
```

Then in your function, set the state:

```
this.setState({messages: updatedMessages})
```

and then map over the messages state, or a `messages` variable in `render`:

```
const messages = this.state.messages;


<ul className="list-inline">
  {messages.map(function(message, key){
etc...
```

Comment: That `setState` call is unsafe for the OP's scenario, because they're updating state based on existing state (adding to the state's `messages` array). When updating state based on existing state, you *must* use the callback form of `setState` because state updates are async and can be merged. Details: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score -1):

put messages array and set state change to render DOM. You should read https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Answer (score -1):

Two issues:

1. You mustn't directly mutate the state object in React (see: [Do Not Directly Modify State](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)). Instead, provide a *new* array via `setState` with the new entry in it.
2. When updating state based on existing state, you must use the function callback version of `setState`, not the version accepting an object, because state updates are asynchronous and may be merged (see: [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), though it's really "will," not "may"). Using the object version often happens to work, but it isn't guaranteed to; indeed, it's guaranteed *not* to, at some point.

Let's look at various ways to update an array:

#### Adding to the end (appending):

```
this.setState(({messages}) => ({
    messages: [...messages, newValue]
}));
```

In your case, `newValue` would be `dataSnapshot.val()`.

*(We need the `()` around the object initializer because otherwise the `{` would seem to start a full function body instead of a concise expression body.)*

#### Adding to the beginning (prepending):

Largely the same, we just insert the new element in a different place:

```
this.setState(({messages}) => ({
    messages: [newValue, ...messages]
}));
```

*(We need the `()` around the object initializer because otherwise the `{` would seem to start a full function body instead of a concise expression body.)*

#### Updating an existing item in the array

Suppose you have an array of objects and want to update one you have in the variable `targetElement`:

```
this.setState(({messages}) => {
    messages = messages.map(element => {
        return element === targetElement
            ? {...element, newValue: "new value"}
            : element;
    });
    return {messages};
}));
```

#### Removing an existing item in the array

Suppose you have an array of objects with `id` values and want to remove the one with `targetId`:

```
this.setState(({messages}) => {
    messages = messages.filter(element => element.id !== targetId);
    return {messages};
}));
```

#### By Index

**Warning:** Updating arrays in React by index is generally not best practice, because state updates are batched together and indexes can be out of date. Instead, work based on an identifying property or similar.

But if you have to use an index and you know it won't be out of date:

```
this.setState(({messages}) => {
    messages = messages.filter((e, index) => index !== targetindex);
    return {messages};
}));
```