# state is not updating in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have tried to update the state when new employee data entered .but the push function is not inserting the new employee data to the state .in the addpar function i have set up console.log and it showed that the data is there but it fail to push it to state

```
 // this class will hold the table and the form 

class EmpContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    // the state will have the following data by default 
      this.state = {participants : [
                    {   id: '1',
                        name: 'Dani', 
                        email: 'dani@hotmail.com',
                        phone: '0443322118'
                    },
                    {   id: '2',
                        name: 'Dani', 
                        email: 'dani@hotmail.com',
                        phone: '0443322118'
                    }
                ]};
    }

    // this supposed to add the new employed data to the state
    addPar (emp){
    console.log(emp); // this shows the new employee data 

    this.state.participants.push(emp);
       this.setState({
         participants: this.state.participants
       });}
render() {
        return (
            <div>
             <AddNewParticipant addNew={this.addPar}/>
            </div>
        );}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've now copied this to [an answer to the dupetarget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46050270/157247) and made this a CW; here's the version tailored to your code.

---

Two issues:

1. You don't directly mutate the state object in React. Instead, provide a *new* array via `setState` with the new entry in it.
2. When updating state based on existing state, use the function callback version of `setState`, not the version accepting an object, because state updates are asynchronous and may be merged.

More in the React documentation: [*Using State Correctly*](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) (the "Do Not Modify State Directly" and "State Updates May Be Asynchronous" sections).

So:

```
addPar(emp) {
    this.setState(function(state) {
        return {
            participants: [...state.participants, emp]
        }
    });
}
```

Or with a concise arrow (we need the `()` around the body expression because we're using an object initializer, and the `{` would otherwise seem to start a verbose function body):

```
addPar(emp) {
    this.setState(state => ({
        participants: [...state.participants, emp]
    }));
}
```