# setState is not updating state properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry, I really miss something with the transmission of `state` within `props` of sub components in React.

I have implemented a version of a todo list with 3 components.

There is a `Form` component and a `ListTodo` component. The state is stored only in the `App` component.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tasks: ["un truc", "autre truc"]
        };
        this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this);
    }

    addTask(task) {
        this.setState({
            tasks: this.state.tasks.push(task)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Form onTaskAdded={ this.addTask }></Form>
                <ListTodo tasks={ this.state.tasks }></ListTodo>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Form extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            task: ""
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            task: event.target.value
        });
    }

    addTask(event) {
        this.props.onTaskAdded(this.state.task);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={ this.addTask }>
                <input placeholder="À faire" onChange={ this.handleChange }></input>
                <input type="submit"></input>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

class ListTodo extends Component {

    render() {
        const tasks = this.props.tasks.map((t, i) => (
                <li key={i}>{t}</li>
            ))

        return (
            <ul>{tasks}</ul>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

The display is good at start so the `ListTodo` achieves to see the prop `tasks`. But after a form submission, I get an error on `ListTodo.render` :

> TypeError: this.props.tasks.map is not a function

When I console.log the `this.props.tasks`, I don't get my array but the length of the array.

Do you know why?

**Edit** : 
Thanks for answers guys, you're right. I missed the behavior of Array.push.

But React seems still odd. If I let the mistaken code
`this.setState({
            tasks: this.state.tasks.push(task)
})`

then a `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state))` displays :

`{"tasks":["un truc","autre truc","aze"]}`.

Very disturbing to not be able to trust a console.log...

Comment: At **least** related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044135/update-array-in-react

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [MDN DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=b):

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
>   **returns the new length of the array**.

[Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=b) never returns the result array, it returns the number, so after adding the first task, `this.state.tasks` becomes a number, and it is throwing the error when you trying to run map on number.

You did the mistake here:

```
addTask(task) {
    this.setState({
        tasks: this.state.tasks.push(task)
    })
}
```

Write it like this:

```
addTask(task) {
    this.setState( prevState => ({
        tasks: [...prevState.tasks, task]
    }))
}
```

Another import thing here is, the new state will be depend on the previous state value, so instead of using `this.state` inside setState, use updater function.

**Explanation about Edit part:**

Two important things are happening there:

**1-** setState is async so just after setState we can expect the updated state value.

Check this for more details about **[async behaviour of setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250)**.

**2-** Array.push always mutate the original array by pushing the item into that, so you are directly mutating the state value by `this.state.tasks.push()`.

---

Check the **[DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)** for more details about setState.

Check the **[MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)** for `spread operator (...)`.

Check this snippet:

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4];

let b = a.push(5);  //it will be a number

console.log('a = ', a);

console.log('b = ', b);
```

Comment: You might say **why**, perhaps even refer to the documentation where it talks about this stuff... Particularly as you changed **two** things (both important).

Comment: You're right. I miss the behavior of Array.push.

But React seems still odd, if I let `this.setState({
   tasks: this.state.tasks.push(task)
  })
`, then a `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state))` displays :
`{"tasks":["un truc","autre truc","aze"]}`
17:12:52.634

Comment: two imp thing here, **1-** setState is async so just after setState we can't expect the updated state value, **2-** you are directly mutating the state value array.push will push the element into main array.

Comment: check [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250) for more details about async behaviour of setState.

Comment: Thanks @MayankShukla! With your answer, I just figure out why the console.log was not "reliable", if I may say so. It's because of the asynchronous behavior of setState, when it is build from himself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in how you *add a task* in the App’s state.

```
addTask(task) {
    this.setState({
        tasks: this.state.tasks.push(task)
    })
}
```

See, [`Array.prototype.push` returns the length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=b) of the array after adding an element. What you really want is [probably `Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=b).

```
addTask(task) {
    this.setState({
        tasks: this.state.tasks.concat([ task ])
    })
}
```

Also, thanks to @t-j-crowder pointers and as also reported by @mayank-shukla, you should use a different approach to mutate your state:

```
addTask(task) {
    this.setState(function (state) {
        return {
            tasks: state.tasks.concat([ task ])
        }
    });
}
```

Or using ES2015 Arrows, Object destructuring and Array spread:

```
addTask(task) {
    this.setState(({ tasks }) => ({
        tasks: [ ...tasks, task ]
    }));
}
```

Since `Component.prototype.setState` *can* be asynchronous, passing a function to it will guarantee the **new state values** depend on the **right, current previous values**.

This means that if two or more `setState` calls happen one after another you are this way sure that the result of the first one will be kept by applying the second.

Comment: You cannot use the object version of `setState` when the new state is derived from the old state. You **must** use the function version to avoid obscure, hard-to-track-down bugs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: Than you, fixed.

Comment: Nice one with the destructuring. :-) I'd recommend removing the incorrect call entirely, though.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers stated, the Array `push` method does not return the array. Just to complement the answers above, if you are using ES6, a nice and elegant way of doing this is using the spread operator (you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator))

```
this.setState({
    tasks: [...this.state.tasks, task]
})
```

It is essentially the same as using the `concat` method, but I think this has a nicer readability.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from Array.push return the number of elements in the array and not the updated array

```
addTask(task) {
  this.setState({
    tasks: this.state.tasks.push(task)
  })
}
```

To fix this you can push to state.tasks then setState with it later on:

```
addTask(task) {
  this.state.tasks.push(task);
  this.setState({
    tasks: this.state.tasks
  })
}
```

This way you set state.task to the updated array.