# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined with web-sockets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, pusher, isomorphic-javascript

Using Isomorphic framework for React and pusher to get websockets.

I can't seem to access state when I am in the `componentDidMount()` function.

```
class TopbarNotification extends Component {
   state = {
     visible: false,
     notifications: []
   };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     notifications: [],
     visible: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxxx', {
       cluster: 'xxx',
       encrypted: true
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('notifications');
    channel.bind('new-notification', function (data) {
      let newNotifications = this.state.notifications.push(data)
      this.setState({
        notifications: newNotifications
      })
      alert(data.message);
    });

  }

  render() {
     // ...Blah blah, blah blah
  }
}
```

I am getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'notifications' of undefined`

Referring to this line: `let newNotifications = this.state.notifications.push(data)`

Why can I not access `state` inside `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: Because you aren't just in `componentDidMount`, you are inside an anonymous function in your `bind` when you call `this`.

Comment: Ahh.. OK. So do you know how I would get state into that function?

Comment: use an arrow function for your new-notification callback method instead of a regular function

Comment: There's also another error here, but I left it out of my answer since it's not relevant to the problem. The push method returns a number (and not the array), so passing `notifications: newNotifications` like you're doing now will probably break. Use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead of `push` to create a new array, then pass that in.

Comment: @waz another mistake is in setState, check this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179671/setstate-is-not-updating-state-properly/46179719#46179719

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `function` given to the `channel.bind` is overshadowing the `this` of `componentDidMount()`. Using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead should do the trick.

```
channel.bind('new-notification', data => {
  let newNotifications = this.state.notifications.push(data)
  this.setState({
    notifications: newNotifications
  })
  alert(data.message);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean like this:     
    `channel.bind('new-notification', data => {
      this.setState({ notifications: [...this.state.notifications, data] });
        console.log(this.state, '---callback');
       });`

Comment: Yeah, that should do it (assuming you're responding to the comment I made on the original question)

Comment: yeah, I was. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you test this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxxx', {
      cluster: 'xxx',
      encrypted: true
    });
    let _this = this;

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('notifications');
    channel.bind('new-notification', function (data) {
      let newNotifications = _this.state.notifications.push(data);
      _this.setState({
        notifications: newNotifications
      })
      alert(data.message);
    });

  }
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This also worked. The arrow function is just a little cleaner.