# Reove element from an array with useState hook (todo app, pros cons app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am trying to get this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyoSW2cP-RE

I am creating an ordered list out of the array elements that part is working fine, but when I delete it's not working, before It deleted everything now it isn't deleting at all

Here is my code, almost working except for the deleting part

```js
function App() {
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState('Should I marry?');
  const [i, setI] = useState(0);
  const classArr = ['lobster', 'gloria', 'elite', 'indie', 'dancing'];
  const [prosArr, setProsArr] = useState([]);
  const [consArr, setConsArr] = useState([]);
  // console.log(prosArr);

  let classFoo = (e, arr) => {
    if (e === 0) {
      document.body.classList.toggle(arr[e]);
      document.body.classList.remove(arr[arr.length - 1]);
    } else if (e === arr.length) {
      document.body.classList.toggle(arr[e - 1]);
    } else {
      document.body.classList.toggle(arr[e - 1]);
      document.body.classList.toggle(arr[e]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div className="main d-flex flex-column justify-content-start align-items-center m-320">
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setQuestion(e.target.value)}
          className="question text-center p-5 h1 m-0"
          value={question}
        />
        <div className="d-flex w-100 flex-wrap justify-content-center">
          <div className="d-flex flex-column h-100 w-50 m-320">
            <div className="title p-5 m-0 h2 d-inline-block text-center text-success w-100">Pros</div>
            <div className="content p-1 h2 d-inline-block text-center text-success w-100 overflow-hidden">
              <ol>
                {prosArr.map((e, key) => {
                  if (e !== '') {
                    //  return <li key={key}><input type="text" onBlur={e=>e.target.value === "" && prosArr.splice(key,1)} defaultValue={e}/></li>

                    return (
                      <li key={key}>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          onBlur={(e) => e.target.value === '' && setProsArr(prosArr.filter((e) => e !== ''))}
                          defaultValue={e}
                        />
                      </li>
                    );
                  } else {
                    return '';
                  }
                })}
                <li>
                  <input
                    onBlur={(e) => {
                      e.target.value !== '' && setProsArr([...prosArr, e.target.value]);
                      e.target.value = '';
                    }}
                    type="text"
                  />
                </li>
                <button onClick={() => console.log(prosArr, 'yo')}>click</button>
                <button
                  onClick={() =>
                    console.log(
                      prosArr.filter((el) => el !== ''),
                      'yo',
                    )
                  }
                >
                  click
                </button>
              </ol>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="d-flex flex-column h-100 w-50 m-320">
            <div className="title p-5 m-0 h2 d-inline-block text-center text-danger w-100">Cons</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        className="m-5 btn btn-dark"
        onClick={() => {
          classFoo(i, classArr);
          if (i === classArr.length) {
            setI(0);
          } else {
            setI(i + 1);
          }
        }}
      >
        Change Font
      </button>
    </section>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```css
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
$light: #C6CACF;
$dark: #4F5966;


.lobster {
  font-family: "Lobster", cursive;
}
.gloria {
  font-family: "Gloria Hallelujah", cursive;
}
.indie {
  font-family: "Indie Flower", cursive;
}
.dancing {
  font-family: "Dancing Script", cursive;
}
.elite {
  font-family: "Special Elite", cursive;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: $light;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.question {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: $dark;
  color: white;
  &::after{
    content: "?";
  }
}

.title {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: $dark solid 2px;
}

.m-320 {
  min-width: 320px;
}

ol {
  padding-left: 10%;
  color: rgb(2, 17, 2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Can you help please I am really stuck and I can't get any useful info on the internet

Comment: See the answers to the linked question (I suggest [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46050270/157247), but.. ;-) ). The important things are: Creating a *new* array to update in state, and using the callback form of the state setter. E.g., if you have `const [array, setArray] = useState([]);`, remove like this: `setArray(a => a.filter(entry => entry !== entryToRemove));` and add to it like this: `setArray(a => [...a, newValue]);`.

Comment: I think I did it that way :/ Can't get it