# Reactjs - Using Object to store Form data as State variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

Previously, I have followed the system where I save each Input in a Form as a React state variable and have a common function to update them.

Now, I am trying to store all the Form data in a single object and store that as a React state variable (as follows).

```js
const [formInputs, setFormInputs] = React.useState({});
    
const onInputChange = (event) => {
    formInputs[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setFormInputs(formInputs);
    console.log("onInputChange => formInputs", formInputs);
};
```

And the Input elements are used as follows:

```html
<input
    type="text"
    name="username"
    placeholder="username"
    value={formInputs.username || ""}
    onChange={onInputChange}
/>
```

Here, the input element always stays empty even after entering data. Seems like the empty string `""` is always being considered rather than `formInputs.username` from this condition: `value={formInputs.username || ""}`

By commenting out this line, it seems to be working. But, I don't think that's the proper way. Please suggest what I have missed here...

[Code-Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-tereshkova-n29i1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) (Please check the `Console` tab for the logs!)

Comment: Duplicate: [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Comment: See the answers to [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044135/update-array-in-react) (and several others :-) ) and [the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). You can't directly modify an object held in state; instead, you have to create a **new** object, for instance: `const onInputChange = ({target: {name, value}}) => { setFormInputs(formInputs => ({...formInputs, [name]: value})); console.log("onInputChange => formInputs", formInputs); };
` (https://pastebin.com/GDKNt8Zb)

Comment: Here's the key to understanding why your code didn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/95nhm6zo/